# Nginx reverse proxy to https location causes ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

ttI am adding an nginx reverse proxy in front of my existing nextcloudpi server in order to be able to route traffic to different servers in my network depending to the domain that is used. Currently the nextcloudpi server is the only one running, so all traffic is directly routed to it.
The server is only accessible via https and letsencrypt handles the certifactes on the nextcloudpi server.

In order to route traffic from my reverse proxy to the nextcloudpi server via https, I have set up the default.conf file to look like this:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;

  server_name <my-public-url>;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://<hostname-of-my-nextcloudpi-server>;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work. Firefox returns `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` and Chrome `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I have also not seen anywhere where traffic is proxied to a http**s** location. I am aware that in my internal network I can and should just route to the target location on port 80 but since the server is already set up to use https I want to keep it that way.

Thanks for your help